# Define sets in a way that equality can be proven by extensionality

Tags: coq

I need to define sets (only finite sets are enough for my usage) in a way that the following lemma can be proved.

```
Lemma set_extensionality: forall X A B,
  (forall x, set_in x A <-> set_in x B) -> A = B.
```

One approach would be use of lists to represent sets but with the additional conditions that lists do not repeat any element and are ascending. Something like

```
Inductive set (X : Type) : Type :=
  | set_cons (l : list X) (Hnd : NoDup l) (Hasc : asc l).
```

But unfortunately I can't define `asc` since I need an order on arbitrary type `X`.

Another approach would be use of predicate as set and add function extensionality as an axiom.

```
Inductive set (X : Type) : Type :=
  | set_cons (P : X -> Prop).
```

But I prefer to not use any axiom or additional hypothesis. any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain extensional equality by forcing the elements of the list to be sorted.  There are many libraries that follow this approach, including my own [Extensional Structures](https://github.com/arthuraa/extructures) (more alternatives are linked on the GitHub page).